bit.dev: error exporting a new express-server template generated component: "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'billingProviderId')"
I am trying to setup a new bit workspace with express-server apps, and am getting an error on exporting to a bit cloud scope, even without any modifications to the template generated component. I can add the component from template, I can build, run, snap, and tag, and status shows OK, however when I run bit export I get the error:
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'billingProviderId')

note: other components export just fine. I successfully created/snapped & exported new components based on the 'module' 'node-env' templates.
running with --log debug shows the error is caused here:
[15:57:04.201]: Http.pushToCentralHub, started. url: https://api.v2.bit.cloud/exporter/api/put. total objects 9
⠍⠁ exporting component[15:57:04.694]: Http.pushToCentralHub, completed. url: https://api.v2.bit.cloud/exporter/api/put, status 200 statusText OK
[15:57:04.696]: http, msg from central-hub: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'billingProviderId')
[15:57:04.700]: got an error from command export: UnexpectedNetworkError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'billingProviderId')
    err: {
      "type": "UnexpectedNetworkError",
      "message": "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'billingProviderId')",
      "stack":
          UnexpectedNetworkError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'billingProviderId')
              at Http.pushToCentralHub (/Users/riverhume/.bvm/versions/1.8.52/bit-1.8.52/node_modules/@teambit/legacy/dist/scope/network/http/http.js:333:13)
              at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
              at async pushAllToCentralHub (/Users/riverhume/.bvm/versions/1.8.52/bit-1.8.52/node_modules/@teambit/export/dist/export.main.runtime.js:561:27)
              at async ExportMain.exportMany (/Users/riverhume/.bvm/versions/1.8.52/bit-1.8.52/node_modules/@teambit/export/dist/export.main.runtime.js:641:27)
              at async ExportMain.exportComponents (/Users/riverhume/.bvm/versions/1.8.52/bit-1.8.52/node_modules/@teambit/export/dist/export.main.runtime.js:321:9)
              at async ExportMain.export (/Users/riverhume/.bvm/versions/1.8.52/bit-1.8.52/node_modules/@teambit/export/dist/export.main.runtime.js:250:9)
              at async ExportCmd.report (/Users/riverhume/.bvm/versions/1.8.52/bit-1.8.52/node_modules/@teambit/export/dist/export-cmd.js:85:9)
              at async CommandRunner.runReportHandler (/Users/riverhume/.bvm/versions/1.8.52/bit-1.8.52/node_modules/@teambit/cli/dist/command-runner.js:130:20)
              at async CommandRunner.runCommand (/Users/riverhume/.bvm/versions/1.8.52/bit-1.8.52/node_modules/@teambit/cli/dist/command-runner.js:85:16)
              at async CLIMain.run (/Users/riverhume/.bvm/versions/1.8.52/bit-1.8.52/node_modules/@teambit/cli/dist/cli.main.runtime.js:230:5)
              at async runCLI (/Users/riverhume/.bvm/versions/1.8.52/bit-1.8.52/node_modules/@teambit/bit/dist/load-bit.js:428:3)
              at async initApp (/Users/riverhume/.bvm/versions/1.8.52/bit-1.8.52/node_modules/@teambit/bit/dist/app.js:63:5)
      "isUserError": true,
      "name": "UnexpectedNetworkError"
    }
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'billingProviderId')
[15:57:04.788]: [+] CLI-OUTPUT: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'billingProviderId')
[15:57:04.788]: [*] the command "export" has been terminated with an error code 1

Steps to reproduce (in an empty directory):
bit init --default-scope <orgname.scopename>
bit create express-server express-test --env <orgname.scopename>
bit snap -m "1st snap"
bit login
bit export

note: same error happens using tag instead of snap
Local environment:

node --version
v20.17.0
bit --version
1.8.52
pnpm --version
9.10.0
npm bvm --version
10.8.2

expected: a successful push to bit.cloud of the successful snap
result: error "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'billingProviderId')"
Thanks!

there was an unrelated backend incident at that time. please run the export again. this issue is unrelated to your implementation.

FWIW I fixed it on my end prior to that incident resolution. The mainPath in the generated .bit-app file was inconsistent with other template-generated components and with example usage shown on bit.cloud express-server template generates a .bit-app file with: mainPath: import.meta.resolve('./my-server-app.app-root.js'), ... and export worked when this was edited to read simply: mainPath: './my-server-app.app-root.js',
